# How to combine two array, but take care for no same elements

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a simple question. Before I have look around, but the answers I find, was mostly for another situation.

I have two arrays with css-properties

```
old=['font-size: 12px;','color: 12px;','border-left: 1px solid red;'];
new=['font-size: 20px;','border-left: 1px solid green;','left:20px;'];
```

How can I combine this both arrays to have at the end an array which contains only unique styles with the properties from the "new" array if there is something change to the old ones?

In the example above, I want to have this result

```
result=['font-size: 20px;','color: 12px;','border-left: 1px solid green;','left:20px;'];
```

At the first time, I try to make a loop through the old elements, split the items at the ":" but then I see a problem about the names of the styles.
If I check if "left" is inside a string it will return true on "left" but also on every other style-names which contains "left" for example margin-left, padding-left...

How I can solve it in the easiest way?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You might create a single array from the two (with the new items at the end) then `reduce` into an object indexed by the substring that comes before the `:` in the strings, and then get the object's entries:

```js
const old = ['font-size: 12px;', 'color: 12px;', 'border-left: 1px solid red;'];
const newArr = ['font-size: 20px;', 'border-left: 1px solid green;', 'left:20px;'];
const resultObj = [...old, ...newArr].reduce((a, str) => {
  const [key, val] = str.split(/: ?/);
  a[key] = val;
  return a;
}, {});
const result = Object.entries(resultObj).map(([key, value]) => `${key}: ${value}`);
console.log(result);
```

Note that `new` is a reserved word - it can't be a variable name.

Comment: year, at the first look, it could be that what i want to do. could you explain me that the "..." brefore "old" and "newArr" will do?

Comment: That's spread syntax, it creates an array composed of the "old" elements, followed by the "new" elements. It's the same as `old.concat(newArr)`

Answer (score 2):

When you have support for `Object.fromEntries`, then:

```js
function mergeCss(...args) {
    return Object.entries(
        Object.fromEntries(args.flatMap(a => a.map(a => a.match(/^[^:\s]*|[^:\s].+$/g))))
    ).map(arg => arg.join(": "));
}

const result = mergeCss(['font-size: 12px;','color: 12px;','border-left: 1px solid red;'],
                        ['font-size: 20px;','border-left: 1px solid green;','left:20px;']);

console.log(result);
```

You can pass more than two arrays to the above function.

Polyfill for  `Object.fromEntries`:

```
Object.fromEntries = arr => 
    Object.assign({}, ...Array.from(arr, ([k, v]) => ({[k]: v}) ));
```

Comment: Need to remember [`flatMap`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flatMap) is a thing more often!

Comment: @prasanth OP provided a polyfill - if you're working in an environment with any kind of transpiling then you probably have access to it already

Answer (score 1):

Use can use [`Object.Values()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/values), [`Array.reduce()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) and [`String.match()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match):

```js
const css1 = ['font-size: 12px;','color: 12px;','border-left: 1px solid red;'];
const css2 = ['font-size: 20px;','border-left: 1px solid green;','left:20px;'];

const merged =
  Object.values(
    [...css1, ...css2].reduce(
      (acc, x) => (acc[x.match(/(.*)\s*:/)[1]] = x, acc), {}));

console.log(merged)
```